# Java won't execute cmd line?

Tags: java, shell, cmd

I try to run this shell in  java but it never works.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" cat *.java|sed '/import/d'|sed'/package/d'>>b.java ");
```

When I change the cmd to something like "`ls`" or "`open foo.java`" the code will works.

Any idea why?

Comment: (1) What actually happens? Are you getting any error messages? (2) Does your command works directly from the shell?

Comment: Yes the command fully worked when I type by hand! the error said file dos not exist.

Comment: Do you run your Java program directly from shell or from some IDE?

Comment: I try with "cat *.java>>a.java". The error is: cat: *.java>>a.java: No such file or directory

Comment: I run java from cmd line

Comment: My best guess is: you have different **current directories** when your command is run directly from shell and from within Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file wildcard pattern is not expanded by a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob). Therefore the pattern is treated literally and the file is not found. You need a shell such as `bash` to interpret this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { 
                   "bash", "-c", 
                   "cat *.java|sed '/import/d'|sed'/package/d'>>b.java" });
```

Make sure to check the contents of [getErrorStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29).

Aside: Consider using the more convenient [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which uses a varargs array to build the command `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

1. the `*.java` part is a glob that is usually expanded by the shell
2. assembling a pipeline from process to process is also a shell feature
3. the output redirection is a shell feature

Basically, you really need to invoke a shell to run this type of pipeline.  The `exec` method runs a specific program with arguments.  You might be able to get this to work by invoking the shell directly and passing the command line as an argument but I doubt that would work either.

You may have to implement the `cat *.java` part by enumerating the directory contents and reading each file separately.  The open separate `Process` instances for each of the `sed` commands and implement the pipeline between them using the input and output streams of the `Process` instances.